ESP32-WROOM-38pin, pin number to control onboard LED
I have one of the boards in the image below, which as far as I can work out is called a ESP32 WROOM devkit 38-pin.
I've successfully flashed micropython, and can obtain a REPL through picocom. I'm trying to follow the standard introductory examples and switch the onboard LED on and off.
>>> from machine import Signal,Pin
>>> led = Signal(2, Pin.OUT)
>>> led.on()

But this isn't working. I can't get the LED to switch on. I tried changing the number to 22 and 25, but this doesn't work either. The LED does flash on and off every time I enter a command into REPL.
I saw someone on reddit complain that several such boards he/she obtained didn't work properly. Is that a possibility here, or have I made some mistake with the commands?


The best advice I can give you is "read the documentation / board description". If you don't have one you could try the Google Image Search to get a description. The second best advice is to write a small program with a loop and try to set all GPIOs in OUTPUT mode and change the level from LOW to HIGH and back (with a 500er delay and output on Serial Monitor) to identify the LED.

led = Pin(2, Pin.OUT), led.value(1). Always read the documentation if you are new. You had a misunderstanding about the Signal object.

Pin(2, Pin.OUT) doesn't work either. As far as I can see, doing led.on() with led as a Signal object is equivalent to led.value(1) with led as Pin object.

This seems to be an ESP32 NodeMCU Development Board:
https://blog.berrybase.de/esp32-node-mcu-module-anfaenger-guide/

I have several 38-pin boards from various vendors.
However, the OP's description of

The LED does flash on and off every time I enter a command into REPL.

seems to be very different from that in my boards.
I doubt the LED is connected to the GPIO (e.g. IO2). It may be connected to the USB-UART chip. In this case, one cannot control it from GPIO pins.

Thanks for the reply. I've learned a bit more, and you're right: LED can't be controlled on this board from GPIO. I can actually switch the LED on through GPIO1, but doing so disables communication with the board.
This is board is available as 'NodeMCU Development Board' from BerryBase:
https://www.berrybase.de/en/esp32-nodemcu-development-board

I see.  In the Espressif's Dev kit (and almost all of the third party dev kits) GPIO1 is used as U0TXD, which is connected to the USB-UART chip. The datasheet they showed in the page you linked was those of a different product.
